# How to move a React component to a new Window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have very complex component which takes long time to render, and I want this component shown in a child Window (created by Window.open()) once the user clicks a button.

So, I'd like to pre-render this component in the main window first, then, just move the **rendered** component into the child window on button click, which could improve the performance since everything has been rendered.

Below is the component that I want to pre-render which might have some sub components:

```
export default observer(function MyComp(props: MyCompProps) {
    ...
    return (
        <div>Some complex sub components</div>
    );
});
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do that. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that React has a rule, all components must have the first capital letter.

About your doubt, you can use the `useState()` hook to set the component's value to false and only when you click on the button it opens inside the window you want.

```
export default observer(function MyComp(props: MyCompProps) {
    const [isOpenComponent, setIsOpenComponent] = useState(false);

function handleOpen() {
  setIsOpenComponent(true);
}
    return (
        <div>
         <div>Some complex sub components</div>
          <div isOpenComponent> Component that you want to open</div>
          <button type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>Open Component</div>
         </div>
        </div>
    );
});
```

This is only an idea to implement your case.